# jQuery Mobile - Dynamic collapsible stop adding after certain number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am trying to use this jQuery Mobile collapsible "add" button stop after so many clicks or adding so many divs etc.

As it stands now it just adds infinite amount.

This is from the demo docs http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/collapsible-dynamic/

```
<button type="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="right" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="add">Add</button>
<button type="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="expand">Expand last</button>
<button type="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="right" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="collapse">Collapse last</button>
<div data-role="collapsibleset" data-content-theme="a" data-iconpos="right" id="set">
<div data-role="collapsible" id="set1" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible content.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
var nextId = 1;
$("#add").click(function() {
    nextId++;
    var content = "<div data-role='collapsible' id='set" + nextId + "'><h3>Section " + nextId + "</h3><p>I am the collapsible content in a set so this feels like an accordion. I am hidden by default because I have the 'collapsed' state; you need to expand the header to see me.</p></div>";
    $( "#set" ).append( content ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
});
$( "#expand" ).click(function() {
    $("#set").children(":last").collapsible( "expand" );
});
$( "#collapse" ).click(function() {
    $( "#set" ).children( ":last" ).collapsible( "collapse" );
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the add button handler, just count the number of current collapsible divs(`$('#set [data-role="collapsible"]').length`), and if your max is already there message the user and exit the function:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var curNumOfDivs = $('#set [data-role="collapsible"]').length;
    if (curNumOfDivs > 4){
        alert("You have exceeded tha max allowed collapsibles!");
        return false;
    }
    nextId++;
    var content = "<div data-role='collapsible' id='set" + nextId + "'><h3>Section " + nextId + "</h3><p>I am the collapsible content in a set so this feels like an accordion. I am hidden by default because I have the 'collapsed' state; you need to expand the header to see me.</p></div>";
    $( "#set" ).append( content ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lt2j69kj/)**